# The proof of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f''(x)=f'(x)$

1. Prove that $V$ is a subspace of the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $F(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where the addition is defined by $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and
   $(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda (f(x))$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
2. Is $V$ a non-zero subspace? Give reasons.

I am just having trouble with proving $V$ is closed under addition and whether $V$ is a non-zero subspace.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a direct consequence of the linearity of the derivative.

For the second consider the well known exponential function $e^x$ or constant functions.

Answer (score 1):

The closure under addition follows from the fact that the derivative of the sum is the sum of the derivatives. The subspace is non zero because the exponential function $e^x$ and all her translates $e^x + c$  have all the derivatives equal to the first.